# How to download files in torrents sequentially

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I am downloading some TV Series using uTorrent .
But I want to download on the basis of the episode ( File name ) sequentially .
So I want the 4th episode to start downloading only after the first three are finished .
Currently I am changing the file priority for 2/3 torrents to high and all others are skipped . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: in utorrent settings, you can enable fine grained file priorities and then in the files tab, just right click and select prioritize by file order. this is effective but can cause some wastage of data...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this question](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=135788) sequential downloading is not supported and won't be. Maybe there are plugins for this for uTorrent.

**Edit**: i did find [this](https://github.com/Ruzzz/uSequential) Plugin for uTorrent. (But you need to check if it works and does what you want.)
([translated page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://ruzzzua.blogspot.com/2010/02/utorrent-sequential-download.html&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhttp://ruzzzua.blogspot.nl/2010/02/utorrent-sequential-download.html%26num%3D20%26safe%3Doff%26complete%3D0%26hl%3Den%26site%3Dwebhp))

But another way to go is [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/).
It has a function *Sequential downloading (aka "Download in order")*.
(You can read about it in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61683/which-torrent-client-has-preview-mode))

However, this feature comes with a [health warning](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/qbittorrent/index.php?title=QBittorrent_2_English_documentation):

> Attempts to download the selected torrents in sequential order.
>   Torrent pieces are usually downloaded in an optimal order which
>   maximizes speed and benefits to the swarm health. Downloading in
>   sequential order is useful for preview files. However, this feature is
>   against Bittorrent protocol recommendations due to its negative effect
>   on the swarm. It is thus discouraged to use this feature. A more
>   detailed explanation of why this feature is bad is available [here](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Sequential_downloading_is_bad)

qBittorrent:

[image: qBittorrent]

Comment: Curious how this is the accepted answer when it refers to a different question. OP asked how to download component files in named order, not pieces of the torrent (if it can even be imagined as a single blob). Anyway, the first link is defunct, so it doesn't support the answer's assertion any more - another example of why link-only sentiments are bad. I wonder if the other 3 context-free links fare any better.

Comment: @underscore_d It was accepted because it answered the question. On the forum (link is indeed dead but [here is another](http://forum.utorrent.com/topic/53864-sequential-file-downloading/?p=316778)) there is multiple times stated that "sequential **file** downloading" will **NOT** be implemented in uTorrent. That alone answered the question (and links go dead in time). I added some edits to solutions as to how it could be achieved (via a plugin or other program). Please note that I'm talking about "sequential **file** downloading" as stated in the question. All the links are about that.

Comment: @underscore_d Also... underscore_d.... if you look at the [revisions](http://superuser.com/posts/669257/revisions) you'll see that my initial answer was definitely NOT a link-only answer. I never give link-only answers. The only thing I could have done extra was copy and paste the entire post from that forum but with my additional information (in [the original answer](http://superuser.com/revisions/669257/1)) it was not necessary.

Comment: Actually it is supported now, see the answer below this one by Denys Popoff. uTorrent CAN download pieces sequentially..

Answer (score 32):

1. Open uTorrent
2. Press **shift+F2** (hold them for the next step)
3. Go to Options -> Preferences -> Advanced

See uTorrent settings with opened parameters bt.sequential_download (use this for sequential download one movie) and bt.sequential_files (use this for sequential download TVseries from in that sequence as specified in torrent file).

Comment: On Mac, it's Option+Command+, to open advanced preferences.

Answer (score 5):

[Tixati](http://www.tixati.com)
supports this out of the box, along with many nifty features.

Here is a demonstration GIF:

[image]

Comment: I love more and more tixati

Answer (score 1):

qbitorrent has 2 options that allows you to 
*download your file in sequentially order* (from the beginning to the end so it allows you to watch it instantly with VLC media player)
*download first and last part preferentially* so you can easily preview the file

Answer (score 1):

uTorrent actually does that. Go to the "File" tab, then select "prioritize by file order".

Comment: Your answer could probably get a little TLC. I'd love to help but I've not had IRC installed in ages. Maybe a screenshot of this process would help the question be much more awesome. I've attempted to make it slightly better, but this would turn it into a good, or even great answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a roundabout way to do this if it's a video on the current 3.5 build of uTorrent.

This used to be an advanced option in uTorrent you could set for all torrents, but now the only way to do it is if you click on the torrent, go to the files tab below the torrent list, rick click the video, Copy Stream URL, open that up with a video player such as VLC and then it will set that file to download sequentially. After that, you can either leave the video running closing the player should keep it downloading sequentially afterward.

Unfortunately, with this method, you have to explicitly trigger it for the video, and cannot have it default to this for all torrents/files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to control what files of a torrent are downloaded first due to the very nature of a Torrent. If it were possible to do so then I would imagine Torrents would lose their viability for a method of downloading files quickly (again, due to the nature in which torrents are executed).

I recall looking something similar to this up a long time ago and was unable to find anything useful. Did a bit of looking around again and got just about the same responses :/

Comment: I was hoping for a script that would skip all files and then download them 3 or 4 at a time .

Answer (score 0):

Hold down Shift+F2 and navigate to *options*, then go to *Advanced* and set

bt.sequential_download

bt.sequential_files

to true.

Comment: Nifty, and still works, I was looking for this a couple days ago and didn't remember about the key combo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the torrent file you are downloading.
2. Select "files" tab.
3. Click on any file
4. Hit Ctrl+A to select all files
5. Right click on the selection and click on "Prioritize by File Order"
6. Done!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rZeJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find an option in the "Options" tab to show detailed info (or you can simply press F5). Now you can view the individual files from the torrent. Right click on any of the files and you'll find the option to Prioritize by File Order.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to mark all Files as "Do Not Download" and then manually mark the files as "Highest Priority" one by one. Of course, the speed will be affected because of this and there's the manual part.